# Print option in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to enable print option in iPhone apps

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you *might* be better asking this at [the Apple Stackexchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Add a `UIButton` labeled "Print", then wire it up to a method that uses a UIAlert to display "What the heck are you going to print *to*?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing in iOS is only available in iOS 4.2.  Since 4.2 is still under NDA, any discussion of printing facilities in 4.2 would be a violation of NDA.

The one place where you can discuss 4.2 without violating the NDA is on Apple's Developer Forums. If you have an Apple Developer account, you can find the forum here (ADC login required): [Developer Forums: iOS 4.2 beta](https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone/ios42beta).